# Is there a way to display my router's bandwidth usage graph on a web page?

Tags: network-monitoring

My router has bandwidth graphs that update once per second. I am building a status screen (as a web page) to be displayed on a TV in our tech department, and I'd like to embed the graph so we can monitor current bandwidth usage. I'd be willing to install DD-WRT, Tomato, or another good firmware if necessary. Are there any prebuilt tools for doing this?

Comment: It has a URL, doesn't it? :)

Comment: [Simple Network Management Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, it has a URL. I've tried putting it in an iframe, but it simply doesn't work. I've also tried hacking apart the monitor but was left with a frustrated mess of code.

Comment: @EEAA I know what SNMP is, but how exactly does that help?

Answer (score 1):

[You're sporting the Linux penguin and have not heard of cacti?](http://www.cacti.net)  I... just don't know what to say.

Comment: Agreed. Get a router that supports SNMP and you'll have more data to know what to do with.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I should have made a comment about that. I did look at Cacti, but the issue there is that it requires me to set up a MySQL server that sits on my network to gather data. Ideally, I'd like a solution that could just sit in an iframe or poll the router for updates without having to set up a dedicated machine for collecting statistics.